# Adding mobile touch to javascript slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, slider

I have a simple slider code that works fine on every device, but only with the nav controls:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 2000);
  });

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 100, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 100, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });
```

And i would like to know if its posible to add mobile touch, so that people can navigate in mobile with out the nav controles. And how can i do it.

Comment: Please include the HTML that shows how you've made the slider.

Comment: I think the [touchstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart), [touchmove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove) and [touchend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend) events will help you.

Comment: thesis my HTML code

<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>